# XML parser for general XML vs parsers for a specific DTD

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, terminology

Is there a term which refers to XML parsers that do not parse unrestricted XML, but instead a specific XML format as specified by a DTD?

I take it that "XML parser" is usually understood to be a parser which can take in any XML document, such as normal DOM or SAX parsers. What is a good way to call a parser which accepts only a well-defined subset (without referring to a specific such subset)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no term for an XML parser that's restricted to a single schema because there's no reason for such a parser to exist.  A nonentity needs no name.

To ask such a question indicates, perhaps, a lack of understanding of the difference between what's required to parse *well-formed* versus *valid* XML:

- *An XML parser* reads arbitrary XML and will report any errors that prevent the document from being *well-formed*.
- *A validating XML parser* goes one step further and will report any errors that prevent the document from being *valid* against a
  given schema (DTD, XSD, RelaxNG, etc).

You may find additional checks being performed beyond what's expressed by a schema, but you won't find dedicated parsers being written to validate XML against a single, specific schema because the general case is already handled very well in both programming library and end-user application forms.

See also [***Well-formed vs Valid XML***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085).